# Location of blockchain locally on different platforms, and structure of blockchain file?

Tags: blockchain

I just downloaded Bitcoin-QT, and torrented a snapshot of the block chain that is a couple weeks old. I put the bootstrap.dat in ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin and started up the app. Right now it is "Importing blocks from disk". Where do the blocks goes once they've been imported? A friend of mine says that the Bitcoin app makes a Merkle tree out of the blocks in the block chain. How is this stored? I want to write a program that takes snapshots of the block chain every couple hours. It would be much better if I could just update a copy of the block chain as needed instead of making an entire new copy and deleting the old copy.

How do I make a bootstrap.dat out of the blkXXXXX.dat files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the .dat files in the following locations:

- Linux: ~/.bitcoin/blocks
- MacOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/blocks
- Windows: %APPDATA%Bitcoin\blocks
- WinXP: C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin\blocks
- Win7/Win8/Vista: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\blocks

I always found the following attached image helpful in order to understand the structure of the dat files. I am sure it will help you too.

[image: .dat files data structure]

Answer (score 0):

In windows it is stored in Local>AppData>Bitcoin folder on linux it is stored in the Bitcoin folder > blockchain and then blkxxx.dat

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10381/creating-my-own-bootstrap-dat