# How do I generate a bootstrap file on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux, dogecoin, bootstrap.dat

I would like to generate a Bitcoin and Dogecoin (qt) bootstrap file on my ubuntu machine. Is there any way to do this? I know it's possible with Windows but I'm on Ubuntu.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Creating my own bootstrap.dat?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10381/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your local blockchain:

```
cd ~/.bitcoin/blocks
```

Or, to bootstrap testnet, find your local testnet blockchain:

```
cd ~/.bitcoin/testnet3/blocks
```

Concatenate all your `blkxxxxx.dat` files and place the result in `bootstrap.dat`:

```
cat blk* > bootstrap.dat
```

**Warning:** Using `tar -cf` (as instructed by [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/34053/18611)) did not work for me.  I'm importing from bitcoind into [btcd](https://github.com/conformal/btcd).

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as

cd /home/USER/.bitcoin/blocks

tar -cf bootstrap.dat blk*

For dogecoin just change the directory to match

Comment: Pretty sure that just creates a tarfile with the blk files in it.

Comment: ya bitcoind seems to recognize that format just fine. might not be a true bootstrap but i have used it successfully on older bitcoin clones. Might not work the same these days. Ill test tonight and update my post as needed

Comment: @Mullick: Were you able to confirm your solution?