# How can i sync only the last month of the blockchain with bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Anyone have any idea how can i do with bitcoin core.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with Bitcoin-core but it's not recommended, You may want to use electrum instead of Bitcoin-core.

You don't have to download the blockchain using electrum.org.

Comment: Not entirely true, AFAIK you still *can* do what was asked with Bitcoin Core, just no longer the recommended option.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've edited the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still do that <s>if someone running a full node (non-pruned) will make you a [`bootstrap.dat`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/42916/75001)</s>.

From https://bitcoin.org/bin/block-chain/README.txt:

> As of Bitcoin Core version 0.10.0 and later, the block chain bootstrap
>   torrent hosted here takes more time to download and import than it would
>   to simply start Bitcoin Core and let it sync itself.
>
> Forum thread on BitcoinTalk:
>   https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145386.0
>
> Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind version 0.7.1 and later supports a special import feature:  If the file "bootstrap.dat" is found in the bitcoin data directory, it will validate and import all blockchain data found in that file.  The following torrent presents a bootstrap.dat file for that feature.

From [https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/846):

> As of Bitcoin Core version 0.10.0 and later, the block chain bootstrap
>   torrent formerly hosted here is *slower* than a direct download using
>   the bitcoin P2P protocol & client.  If you want the torrent for other
>   reasons, please visit:
>
> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145386.0
>
> To download the latest version of Bitcoin Core, please visit:
>
> https://bitcoin.org/en/download

Further reading, the linked [bitcoin.talk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145386.0) page:

> Updated:  August 23, 2014

Also checking https://bitcoin.org/bin/block-chain/:

> 24-Aug-2014 01:40

I think you can still do this if someone running a full node (non-pruned) will make you a [`bootstrap.dat`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/42916/75001) *however* your trust in the provider must be implicit.

If you want to keep only a limited number of blocks, enable `prune={bytes}` with bytes > 550 in your `bitcoin.conf` file.

Comment: This is not a reasonable answer. Bootstrap files are not verified by the node and are no longer the suggested way of initial sync.

Comment: @Ron There are always caveats. Yes, you must trust that the supplier of the file is honest and is on the right chain. I *thought* that each block was still validated albeit that the node has no knowledge of whether it is on the right chain. Somewhat different importing a bootstrap for only the last month to doing so for initial sync. Otherwise, the answer is, no - there is no way. Possibly I misinterpreted the question, thinking the OP was otherwise up to date.

Comment: There have always been caveats with using a bootstrap file but it was no longer suggested beginning with 0.10.0 due to the introduction of a faster synchronization algorithm. See https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/846

Comment: @Ron A useful link - I was aware the answer was something like that third-hand but had not actually read it myself

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note that the official information from bitcoin.org says that the node will validate and import all blockchain data found in that file when using bootstrap.dat.